# How to make Public folder sharable over the network in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I'd like to make the Public folder (in my Home folder) sharable and writable over my internal network in Ubuntu 22.10. Is there a way to do this from the GNOME user interface?

I recall, in prior versions of Ubuntu (21.10) there was an easy way to do this (I think from the Public folder's Properties popup). However, the new Properties dialog in GNOME 43 does not have this option.

I have already installed ssh and Samba, and I use Nautilus as my file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the `nautilus-share` package to enable Nautilus to share folders using Samba.

   ```
   apt install nautilus-share
   ```

   This will add a "Sharing Options" context menu item in Nautilus.
2. Enable folder sharing to the `Public` folder.

   - Right click on your `Public` folder, and select "Sharing Options".
   - Check-mark "Share this folder"
   - Check-mark "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder"
   - Check-mark "Guest access (for people without a user account)"
   - Click <kbd>Create Share</kbd>
     [image: Folder Sharing Dialog]
3. Relax the permissions of the user's home directory.

   This is a security risk *.

   With Ubuntu 22.04, the file [permissions on users' home folders were changed](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/private-home-directories-for-ubuntu-21-04-onwards/19533?u=d0od), restricting Samba's ability to share sub-directories over the network.

   The original permissions were `drwxr-xr-x` (`755`), which permitted other users to view the the contents of all home directories. In 22.04, the permissions were restricted to `drwxr-x---` (`750`), so only the owner could view the contents of their own home directory.

   Therefore, we must revert the permissions of the user's home directory to `drwxr-xr-x` (`755`).

   ```
   chmod o+rx $(whoami)
   ```

   This is a security risk *. (To undo this change, execute `chmod u=rwx,o+rx,o= $(whoami)`).

   * There is a better more secure way to handle this by editing the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, but I have not tried that. I may edit this answer in the future and add that.
4. Afterwords, you will be to access your `Public` folder across the network using:

   ```
   \\<YOUR COMPUTER>\Public
   ```

Comment: Why the negative points. Does the work-around not work?

Comment: probably a stupid question but: do I need to install and set SAMBA first?

Comment: Yes: `sudo apt install samba`.